# Doctrine 2 createQueryBuilder with same result

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have 2 different QueryBuilders which return the same result. The first QueryBuilder returns the right result. The second QueryBuilder returns the result of the first one.

The question: How to enforce the second QueryBuilder to get data from database and not from memory ?

Usage:

```
/** @var SectionEntity $section */
foreach ( $subject->getSections() as $section ) {
    /** @var QuestionEntity $question */
    foreach ( $section->getQuestions() as $question ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is how I call the QueryBuilders:

```
/** @var SubjectEntity $subject */
$subject = $this->retrieveDefaultProfileQuestions();

/** @var SubjectEntity $old_subject */
$old_subject = $this->retrieveProfileQuestionsForUser( $user );
```

The functions:

```
/**
 * Retrieves default profile questions from database
 *
 * @return null|SubjectEntity
 * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException
 */
private function retrieveDefaultProfileQuestions() {
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder( 's' );
    $query        = $queryBuilder
        ->select( 's, sc, q' )
        ->leftJoin( 's.sections', 'sc' )
        ->leftJoin( 'sc.questions', 'q', 'WITH', 'q.user IS NULL' )
        ->where( 's.type = :TYPE' )
        ->setParameter( 'TYPE', 'profile' )
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
}

/**
 * Retrieves user's profile questions from database
 *
 * @param UserEntity $user
 *
 * @return null|SubjectEntity
 * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException
 */
private function retrieveProfileQuestionsForUser( $user ) {
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder( 's' );
    $query        = $queryBuilder
        ->select( 's, sc, q' )
        ->leftJoin( 's.sections', 'sc' )
        ->leftJoin( 'sc.questions', 'q', 'WITH', 'q.user = :USER' )
        ->where( 's.type = :TYPE' )
        ->setParameter( 'USER', $user )
        ->setParameter( 'TYPE', 'profile' )
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

Comment: `Query`/`QueryBuilder` should always go to DBMS whether you previously did/did not load entity. Have you tried looking into `dev` log in order to catch raw query that is being executed?

Comment: The queries executet are different by the parameter `USER` which in one case is NULL and in the other is an UserEntity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could come from the query that you are sending to mysql, it can be the same as previous so in this case mysql will not build a new `execution plan` and will get you result from memory, one thing that I suggest you to try, is to change the `->select( 's, sc, q' )` into `->select( 's.*, sc.*, q.*' )`